# Track upload progress of multiple files in angular $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, upload

I am trying to upload multiple files using below code.

Scenario : I am recording the video of question 1 then it is uploaded via `$http.post()`. while uploading the first question 2nd questions is being recorded and it is submitted. It continues till the last question.

Problem : When I am uploading the first file, uploadEventHandlers shows progress correctly and I am able to track it's progress, but when at a time multiple questions are being uploaded simultaneously I cant track the progress of multiple files separately.

How can I track the progress of each file individually?
following is the working code snippet. Please suggest the modifications.

```js
var fd1 = new FormData();
fd1.append('iid', iid); //invitation id
fd1.append('qid', scope.$root.current_que + 1); //question id
scope.cq = scope.$root.current_que + 1;
scope.$apply();
fd1.append('file', this.recordedData);
//console.log();
scope.uploading = true;
scope.$root.waitforupload = true;
$http.post(scope.opts.uploadUrl, fd1, {
    transformRequest: angular.identity,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': undefined
    },
    eventHandlers: {
        progress: function(c) {
            console.log('Final : ' + c.loaded + ' of ' + c.total);
        }
    },
    uploadEventHandlers: {
        progress: function(e) {
            console.log("Current : " + e);
            console.log("Uploading Question " + (scope.cq) + " : " + Math.round((e.loaded / e.total) * 100) + "%");
        }
    },
}).then(function(response) {
   //Other Snippet
});
```